# How to run this Chmod.java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is the link to the example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Chmod.java

The code in this example is as follows:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Chmod {

    public static Changer compile(String exprs) {
        // minimum is who and operator (u= for example)
        if (exprs.length() < 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mode");

        // permissions that the changer will add or remove
        final Set<PosixFilePermission> toAdd = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
        final Set<PosixFilePermission> toRemove = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();

        // iterate over each of expression modes
        for (String expr: exprs.split(",")) {
            // minimum of who and operator
            if (expr.length() < 2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mode");

            int pos = 0;

            // who
            boolean u = false;
            boolean g = false;
            boolean o = false;
            boolean done = false;
            for (;;) {
                switch (expr.charAt(pos)) {
                    case 'u' : u = true; break;
                    case 'g' : g = true; break;
                    case 'o' : o = true; break;
                    case 'a' : u = true; g = true; o = true; break;
                    default : done = true;
                }
                if (done)
                    break;
                pos++;
            }
            if (!u && !g && !o)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mode");

            // get operator and permissions
            char op = expr.charAt(pos++);
            String mask = (expr.length() == pos) ? "" : expr.substring(pos);

            // operator
            boolean add = (op == '+');
            boolean remove = (op == '-');
            boolean assign = (op == '=');
            if (!add && !remove && !assign)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mode");

            // who= means remove all
            if (assign && mask.length() == 0) {
                assign = false;
                remove = true;
                mask = "rwx";
            }

            // permissions
            boolean r = false;
            boolean w = false;
            boolean x = false;
            for (int i=0; i<mask.length(); i++) {
                switch (mask.charAt(i)) {
                    case 'r' : r = true; break;
                    case 'w' : w = true; break;
                    case 'x' : x = true; break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mode");
                }
            }

            // update permissions set
            if (add) {
                if (u) {
                    if (r) toAdd.add(OWNER_READ);
                    if (w) toAdd.add(OWNER_WRITE);
                    if (x) toAdd.add(OWNER_EXECUTE);
                }
                if (g) {
                    if (r) toAdd.add(GROUP_READ);
                    if (w) toAdd.add(GROUP_WRITE);
                    if (x) toAdd.add(GROUP_EXECUTE);
                }
                if (o) {
                    if (r) toAdd.add(OTHERS_READ);
                    if (w) toAdd.add(OTHERS_WRITE);
                    if (x) toAdd.add(OTHERS_EXECUTE);
                }
            }
            if (remove) {
                if (u) {
                    if (r) toRemove.add(OWNER_READ);
                    if (w) toRemove.add(OWNER_WRITE);
                    if (x) toRemove.add(OWNER_EXECUTE);
                }
                if (g) {
                    if (r) toRemove.add(GROUP_READ);
                    if (w) toRemove.add(GROUP_WRITE);
                    if (x) toRemove.add(GROUP_EXECUTE);
                }
                if (o) {
                    if (r) toRemove.add(OTHERS_READ);
                    if (w) toRemove.add(OTHERS_WRITE);
                    if (x) toRemove.add(OTHERS_EXECUTE);
                }
            }
            if (assign) {
                if (u) {
                    if (r) toAdd.add(OWNER_READ);
                      else toRemove.add(OWNER_READ);
                    if (w) toAdd.add(OWNER_WRITE);
                      else toRemove.add(OWNER_WRITE);
                    if (x) toAdd.add(OWNER_EXECUTE);
                      else toRemove.add(OWNER_EXECUTE);
                }
                if (g) {
                    if (r) toAdd.add(GROUP_READ);
                      else toRemove.add(GROUP_READ);
                    if (w) toAdd.add(GROUP_WRITE);
                      else toRemove.add(GROUP_WRITE);
                    if (x) toAdd.add(GROUP_EXECUTE);
                      else toRemove.add(GROUP_EXECUTE);
                }
                if (o) {
                    if (r) toAdd.add(OTHERS_READ);
                      else toRemove.add(OTHERS_READ);
                    if (w) toAdd.add(OTHERS_WRITE);
                      else toRemove.add(OTHERS_WRITE);
                    if (x) toAdd.add(OTHERS_EXECUTE);
                      else toRemove.add(OTHERS_EXECUTE);
                }
            }
        }

        // return changer
        return new Changer() {
            @Override
            public Set<PosixFilePermission> change(Set<PosixFilePermission> perms) {
                perms.addAll(toAdd);
                perms.removeAll(toRemove);
                return perms;
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * A task that <i>changes</i> a set of {@link PosixFilePermission} elements.
     */
    public interface Changer {
        /**
         * Applies the changes to the given set of permissions.
         *
         * @param   perms
         *          The set of permissions to change
         *
         * @return  The {@code perms} parameter
         */
        Set<PosixFilePermission> change(Set<PosixFilePermission> perms);
    }

    /**
     * Changes the permissions of the file using the given Changer.
     */
    static void chmod(Path file, Changer changer) {
        try {
            Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = Files.getPosixFilePermissions(file);
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file, changer.change(perms));
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Changes the permission of each file and directory visited
     */
    static class TreeVisitor implements FileVisitor<Path> {
        private final Changer changer;

        TreeVisitor(Changer changer) {
            this.changer = changer;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            chmod(dir, changer);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            chmod(file, changer);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
            if (exc != null)
                System.err.println("WARNING: " + exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            System.err.println("WARNING: " + exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("java Chmod [-R] symbolic-mode-list file...");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2)
            usage();
        int argi = 0;
        int maxDepth = 0;
        if (args[argi].equals("-R")) {
            if (args.length < 3)
                usage();
            argi++;
            maxDepth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        // compile the symbolic mode expressions
        Changer changer = compile(args[argi++]);
        TreeVisitor visitor = new TreeVisitor(changer);

        Set<FileVisitOption> opts = Collections.emptySet();
        while (argi < args.length) {
            Path file = Paths.get(args[argi]);
            Files.walkFileTree(file, opts, maxDepth, visitor);
            argi++;
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly I am using the Netbeans IDE. I have very little knowledge of how chmod works because i am not a linux user.
How should this chmod.java work? Basically you don't need to explain everything as I will learn it by myself if the code already works.

Here is the arguments i have tried on netbeans

```
-R u+w,o-rwx C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\chin.txt
```

But it gives an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at      sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:192)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
at java.nio.file.Files.getPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2004)
at chmod.Chmod.chmod(Chmod.java:269)
at chmod.Chmod$TreeVisitor.visitFile(Chmod.java:294)
at chmod.Chmod$TreeVisitor.visitFile(Chmod.java:279)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
at chmod.Chmod.main(Chmod.java:336)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a true question but a blatant beg for code. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: `"Basically you don't need to explain everything as I will learn it by myself"` - This question demonstrates otherwise.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not begging for code, the code is already there, i just need it to work. Like How to correctly use it to get it to work via arguments.

Comment: It calls this:  Files.getPosixFilePermissions()

The hint is in the name, PosixFilePermissions, it won't work on Windows. This is the problem. Try it on linux, it'll be fine.

Comment: This way of asking the question might help on getting answers.

Comment: And here is the javadoc so you can read up yourself :):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)

Comment: @ThePerson Yes i am using windows 8.1, and since it's not compatible then i guess it's pointless to do this example afterall.

Answer (score 2):

You use a Windows filesystem and chmod expects a filesystem which supports POSIX; which Windows, well, doesn't.

As a proof, try and do that:

```
final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault(); // <-- that's your filesystem
System.out.println(fs.supportedFileAttributeViews());
```

You won't see `posix` displayed.

If you want to play with it, try and use [`memoryfilesystem`](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem) which does have a way to build a `FileSystem` with Unix-like capabilities:

```
final FileSystem fs = MemoryFileSystemBuilder.newLinux()
    .build("testfs");

// fs.getPath() etc
```

Also have a look at [this project](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more), with which you can do that:

```
MoreFiles.setMode(somePath, 0644); // for instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful library. Was struggling to set my file to readable. I was trying code like `Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Path.of(path), PosixFilePermissions.fromString("-rw-r--r--"));` and I got an error saying "invalid mode". The code `MoreFiles.setMode(somePath, 0644);` worked.